# Android Studio and VS Code stuck on "Syncing files to device" when trying to debug flutter app on iOS simulator with M1 mac

Tags: flutter, android-studio, apple-m1, flutter-ios

I am working on a flutter app with my M1 MacBook Pro and can't get the debugger of Android Studio or VS Code to work with an iOS simulator (iPhone 14 Pro with iOS 16.2). When I try to start debugging in Android Studio I get this output in the console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9,5s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62652/S84BCtJtulI=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Pro...
```

After that nothing happens.
I tried running the simulator via Rosetta, but that did not help.

It is running fine with `flutter run` and from Xcode itself but I want the debugger in Android Studio (or VS Code).

This is the result for `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.7.0-13.0.pre.41, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale de-DE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Helps for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525855/1271271

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you prioritize the installation of the Android toolchain, as it constitutes a crucial component that may have been overlooked previously